# How to install a third party library for Printable module using composer (D8)?

Tags: 8, installation

I installed the "Printable" module but it doesn't work. When I try to configure the PDF for the Printable module it says:

"You are seeing no PDF generating tool because you have not installed any third party library using composer".

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have installed your Drupal site. There is a long description on how to use composer on [Drupal.org handbook section](https://www.drupal.org/node/2404989).

The short version is this:

- If you have installed Drupal 8 as you did with Drupal 7 using [composer_manager](https://drupal.org/project/composer_manager) module (which is depricated now)
- If you have installed Drupal 8 using composer, you can require Drupal modules using composer, which automatically will download dependcies (assuming module developers has done their job by adding this information in their module's composer.json file)

Comment: I did a manual installation of Drupal 8.
It seems Composer is taking over and a better way to do it?

I'm a newbie, trying to figure out how to install Drupal 8 with Composer:
Most instructions are for servers (I'm on shared hosting), and there seems to be more than one way of doing it - 

should I just run the following or is there a better option?
composer create-project drupal/drupal my_site_name 8.1.*@dev

Comment: @Gerhard I use a customized version of https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project. Makes it possible to setup your entire site as a composer application where drupal is one of the dependencies.

Comment: my first step is to install Composer - this seems to be a good way to install composer?
https://getcomposer.org/download/

I use shared hosting, in this article ( https://www.pcextreme.nl/community/d/138-drush-installation-for-drupal-shared-hosting ) they don't install Composer as root but in a created folder called "bin" - is that necessary or recommended?

It seems that Composer installs Drush automatically, is that correct?

composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction